# Why non-believers are not going to Heaven?

Tags: non-muslim, jannah

Salaam,
Someone told me that only Muslims can go to Heaven but a thing just hit my mind that if a Person is born and raised in a country such as Israel where Jews are in a majority and he is the son of a poor Jew and he never left the country and died at the age of 40 . Shall he not go to heaven because he never recieved the messege of Allah ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fate of someone who died never having heard of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-having-heard-of-islam). Also check out [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/do-non-muslims-have-a-chance-to-go-to-paradise) and my answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35457/17702).

Answer (score 1):

Those who haven't heard or received the message of Islam, will be given a chance in the judgment day to obey Allah.

Allah is Just, He doesn't punish or hold you accountable before you receive the message

> Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And
>   whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear
>   the burden of another. And never would We punish until We sent a
>   messenger. 17.15

Also check how angels address those who will enter Hell

> And those who disbelieved will be driven to Hell in groups until, when
>   they reach it, its gates are opened and its keepers will say, "**Did
>   there not come to you messengers from yourselves, reciting to you the
>   verses of your Lord and warning you of the meeting of this Day of
>   yours?" They will say, "Yes**, but the word of punishment has come into
>   effect upon the disbelievers. 39.71